# lumen-passport Authentication - $request->user() not setting

Tags: passport.js, lumen

I am struggling to login a user using [lumen-passport](https://packagist.org/packages/dusterio/lumen-passport). I have followed the instructions in the link I just supplied but cannot seem to set the user to use in the `$request` variable of via the `Auth` facade.

As long as I have my guard driver set to `passport` in `auth.php` I cannot get into this block inside `AuthServiceProvider.php boot() method` no matter what I seem to do:

```
Auth::viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
    if ($request->input('api_token')) {
        return User::where('api_token', $request->input('api_token'))->first();
    }
});
```

But even if I try manually return a User record before that call the user is never set, and if I try the following:

```
Auth::setUser(User::where('id', 1);
```

I get this message:

```
InvalidArgumentException in AuthManager.php line 99:
Auth guard driver [api] is not defined.
```

My query above is definitely returning a record from the `User` table as well. It's just I cannot get around to setting it so I can access it in my application via the `$request->user()` method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this really has me puzzled. If it helps at all this is  `my auth.php` config.

```
'defaults' => [
    //'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'api'),
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    //'api' => ['driver' => 'api'],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => \App\User::class
    ]
],

'passwords' => [
    //
],
```

];